# Find all solutions to $ z$ using the quadratic formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, quadratics

Find all $z$ such that $$z^3 + (i-1)z^2 - iz = 0$$

$$z = (1-i)/2 + \sqrt{(i-1)^2 +4i}/2$$
$$ z= (1-i)/2 + \sqrt{2i}/2$$

I'm not sure where to go from this since we have a square root of a complex number. What's the next step?

Comment: Use that $\,(1-i)^2+4i=(1+i)^2\,$. Also, don't forget the $\,\pm\,$ signs.

Comment: Ok, so then $z = 1, i$. Thank you @dxiv

Comment: Careful with the signs. Also, don't forget that you are looking to find *three* roots.

Comment: How is the third root found? How did you know there is a third root? UPDATE: I see it now. $z=0,1,i$

Comment: The original equation is a cubic, which has three complex roots (counting multiplicities) by the [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra). To reduce it to a quadratic, you presumably canceled out a factor of $\,z\,$, but you can only do that if $\,z \ne 0\,$. In this case, however, $\,z=0\,$ *is* a root of the original equation, which got lost along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Alt. hint: $z^3 + (i-1)z^2 - iz = z(z^2-z + i z - i)=z\big(z(z-1)+i(z-1)\big)=\ldots$